# how to improve curl class

Tags: php, curl

I need help to adjustment this curl

i have 100 rows in sql table will call curl class

```
$curl = new cURL();
$q=$sql->query("SELECT * FROM users limit $start,$limi");
while($r = $sql->fetch($q))
{

$curl->cURL($r['proxy'],$r['ip']);
$curl->proc('http://site.info/index.php',array('name'=>'username','password'=>'pass123'));
}
```

now we are go to curl class

```
class cURL {

    public $headers;
    public $user_agent;
    public $compression;
    public $agent;
    public $proxy;
    public $process;
    public $url;
     public $cookie;
     public $path;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->process = curl_init();

    }

    public function cURL($proxy,$agent) {
        $this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
        $this->headers[] = 'charset=UTF-8';
        $this->user_agent = $agent;
        $this->compression = 'gzip,deflate';
        $this->proxy = $proxy;
        $this->agent = $agent;
        $this->path  = dirname(__FILE__) .'\temp\/';
        $this->cookie  = $this->path .'cookie.txt';
        if (!is_dir($this->path)) mkdir($this->path, 0755, true);
    }



    public function proc($url,$data=null,$nobody=false) {
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_NOBODY,$nobody);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_ENCODING, $this->compression);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

        if (strpos(curl_exec($this->process),'Login') !==false){

        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         }


         return curl_exec($this->process);

    }

}
```

The problem sql while loop limit 20 users

every call curl function will open index page if the cookie was expired will post login data and go to

1. open index and fetch some data if my condition is pass will call function $curl->proc() and post new data
2. open page number 2  and fetch some data if my condition is pass will call function $curl->proc() and post new data
3. open page number 3  and fetch some data if my condition is pass will call function $curl->proc() and post new data

all this Operations will run one by one take long time in while loop this is issue number 1

issue number 2 
some time in need to call page with out proxy  and i was set proxy $curl->cURL($r['proxy'],$r['ip']);

**The desired thing**

1. in my case what is the best curl_init or culr_multi_init
2. how to improve class to get result In the shortest possible time
3. save respond to hard disk and use file_get_contents to preg_much or use preg_much direct from respond is faster
4. are There tips for improving quality and speed

Thank you